# What would happen in DSA/ECDSA if there were a collision in $r$ but not $k$?

Tags: dsa

In DSA, the value of $r$ is generated as:

$r = (g^k \bmod p) \bmod q$

ECDSA is similar, using the $x$ coordinate of the generator $g$ scalar-multiplied by $k$, again taken modulo $q$.

It's well-known, particularly by Sony, that $k$ must be different for each message signed, or the private key leaks.

Due to the construction, it is possible, but unlikely, to generate two different $k$ values that result in the same $r$ value.  If you happen to generate two signatures of different messages that have the same $r$ value but different $k$ values, does it break security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you happen to generate two signatures of different messages that have the same $r$ value but different $k$ values, does it break security?

No, it doesn't break security.

Suppose you happened up use two different $k$ values ($k$ and $k'$) that just happened to result in the same $r$.  Then, when you publish the corresponding $s$ values, you would publish:

$$s = k^{-1} (H(m) + xr)$$

$$s' = k'^{-1} (H(m') + xr)$$

with $s, s', r, H(m), H(m')$ known.

That leaves $k, k', x$ are three unknown variables; for any possible $x$ value (which is the private key), there are $k, k'$ values that make these equations fit, hence we cannot deduce the value of $x$ from these two equations.

In contrast, if we also knew that $k = k'$ (that is, if the actual $k$ value was reused), then that drops the number of unknown variables to two; in that case, it's just a pair of linear equations in two variables - quite easy to solve.

Comment: If it were two signatures of the same message (in an implementation using random $k$), this reveals the ratio between $k$ and $k'$: $s's^{-1} \equiv k{k'}^{-1} \pmod q$. I don't know how that would be useful, though.

Comment: @Myria: it wouldn't particularly matter; the attacker is actually interested in $x$, and (by the above logic), all $x$ values are still possible.  Now, the attacker will also know the value $z$ such that $(g^x \bmod p) \equiv (g^{zx} \bmod p) \pmod q $; there's no feasible way to use that relation to recover $x$; even if the attacker were given the values $g^{x} \bmod p$, $g^{zx} \bmod p$, it would still be infeasible...